# Prove that $\int_0^1\int_x^1 \frac{f(y)}ydy\,dx=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$ if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose f is a Lebesgue integrable function on [0,1] and define a new function by $$g(x)= \int_x^1 \frac{f(y)}y\text dy$$ for all x in [0,1]. Prove that

$$\int_0^1{g(x)}\text dx=\int_0^1{f(x)}\text dx$$

My approach: I thought of Fubini or Tonelli's theorem to use. But looks like that didn't work well. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

differentiating:
$$
g'(x) = -\frac{f(x)}{x}
$$
so 
$$
f(x) = - xg'(x) 
$$

integrating, then using parts for RHS
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\text dx = -\int_0^1 g'(x) x \text dx = [-xg(x)]_0^1 + \int_0^1 g(x) \text dx
$$
and
$$
[-xg(x)]_0^1 =0
$$
since $g(1)=0$

Comment: glad to be of assistance ;-)

Comment: Is $g$ even differentiable?

Comment: good question. i think in this context (measure theoretic) $\frac{f}{x}$ is called the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $g$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1\int_x^1\frac{f(y)}{y}dydx=\int_0^1 \int_0^y\frac{f(y)}{y}dxdy=\int_0^1 \frac{f(y)}{y}\cdot ydy=\int_0^1 f(y)dy$$

Comment: kindly walk me through how you got this.... $$\int_0^1 \int_0^y\frac{f(y)}{y}dxdy$$

Comment: It's just Fubini's theorem. By tracking the region of integration, you will find that the region is exactly the triangle with vertices $(0,0),(1,1)$ and $(0,1)$. Thus integrating first via $x$, we will have $x$ integrating from $0$ to $y$.

Comment: you ended up with $$\int_0^1 f(y)dy$$ instead of $$\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$ how can one make change of subject?

Comment: But I don't see the difference.. What's your question?

Comment: The last part of yours is in terms of y. The problem has it in terms of x.... how do we change that?

Comment: $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ is the same as $\int_0^1 f(y)dy$. It doesn't matter which symbol you use. For instance $\int_0^1 x^2+e^xdx=\int_0^1 y^2+e^ydy$

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks so much Golbez. You are indeed a life saver. I do appreciate your time and immense effort in helping me out...